# How do I extract consonants from a string field?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I extract only the consonants from a field in records that contain names?

For example, if I had the following record in the `People` table:

| Field | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Richard |

How could I extract only the consonants in "Richard" to get "R,c,r,d"?

Comment: I've edited your question for formatting, please don't use all-caps when posting. Also, please provide more information about the expected return value. Are you looking for a comma-delimited list of the consonants? Just a string with the vowels removed?

Comment: R,c,r,d? Where did the h go? Or do you consider it to be a vowel?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean "how can I remove all vowels from the input" so that `'Richard'` becomes `'Rchrd'`, then you can use the `translate` function as Boneist has shown, but with a couple more subtle additions.

First, you can completely remove a character with `translate`, if it appears in the second argument and it doesn't have a corresponding "translate to" character in the third argument.

Second, alas, if the third (and last) argument to `translate` is `null` the function returns `null` (and the same if the last argument is the empty string; there is a very small number of instances where Oracle does **not** treat the empty string as `null`, but this is not one of them). So, to make the whole thing work, you need to add an extra character to both the second and the third argument - a character you do NOT want to remove. It may be anything (it doesn't even need to appear in the input string), just not one of the characters to remove. In the illustration below I use the period character (`.`) but you can use any other character - just not a vowel.

Pay attention too to upper vs lower case letters. Ending up with:

```
with
  sample_inputs (name) as (
    select 'Richard' from dual union all
    select 'Aliosha' from dual union all
    select 'Ai'      from dual union all
    select 'Ng'      from dual
  )
select name, translate(name, '.aeiouAEIOU', '.') as consonants
from   sample_inputs
;

NAME      CONSONANTS
-------   ----------
Richard   Rchrd  
Aliosha   lsh    
Ai               
Ng        Ng
```

Comment: And sometimes 'y', 'Y'! :)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - technically, "vowels" and "consonants" are kinds of sounds, not kinds of letters. That is relevant to English, where sound-letter is many-to-many. In any case, also technically, English grammar classifies letters, somewhat abusively, into 5 vowels and 21 consonants. Not my (or the OP's) definition; if we want to use our own, different definition, that is fine, but we shouldn't use names that are already defined and broadly accepted.

Comment: well there's no 'Y' in 'Richard' so it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to string a couple replace functions together

```
Select replace(replace(Value, 'A', ''), 'E', '')),...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with the `translate()` function, e.g.:

```
WITH people AS (SELECT 'Name' field, 'Richard' val FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Name' field, 'Siobhan' val FROM dual)
SELECT field, val, TRANSLATE(val, 'aeiou', ',,,,,') updated_val
FROM   people;

FIELD VAL     UPDATED_VAL
----- ------- -----------
Name  Richard R,ch,rd
Name  Siobhan S,,bh,n
```

The translate function simply takes a list of characters and - based on the second list of characters, which defines the translation - translates the input string.

So in the above example, the `a` (first character in the first list) becomes a `,` (first character in the second list), the `e` (second character in the first list) becomes a `,` (second character in the second list), etc.

N.B. I really, really hope your key-value table is just a made-up example for the situation you're trying to solve, and not an actual production table; in general, key-value tables are a terrible idea in a relational database!

Comment: OK thanks, instead if I wanted to extract the 1,2,3 consonant of a name? And if a name does not contain three consonants then take the first ones that are there and add the first vowel

Comment: Then you would need to ask that in a new question.